# API for getting list of vendors in a specific airport

Tags: api, location

My question is quite specific. I'm not looking for a list of nearby airports - that's easy and I know how to do it. What I'm looking for is an API that can give me a list of shops/stores/vendors in an airport. 
From there, it would be helpful if there was a way to get the location of those shops/stores/vendors or their distance from a terminal.

If anyone knows of such a thing, please let me know!

Comment: I didn't find any APIs, but I did find an API vendor that has the data. It doesn't look like their current APIs offer what you are looking for, but maybe if you ask... Here is the vendor's [map of Chicago O'Hare](http://www.flightstats.com/go/AirportTerminalMaps/interactiveMap.do?airportCode=ORD)

Comment: Are you open to paid APIs? Also, is this for U.S. airports only (or some other country for that matter)?

Comment: US airports at a minimum and yes, can be paid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/airport?apicat=Shopping) from *programmableweb* which is a good source of informations and a lot of search on the web, there is no referenced API for what you're looking for. But maybe you can cross datas from airports localizations and shops to do the job

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @ElvinD, you can use [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) to search for nearby places using the airport location you get from another API call (results -> geometry -> location).

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to create a google places similar application? As of the moment, Google has this similar function and currently been updating.

see their [Google Places API docs](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) if it helps.

Comment: yeah... but I can't get specific data on entities within another entity such as an airport